# How To Stop Excel From Becoming Non-Responsive When Using Sleep

Tags: vba, excel

I'm playing with excel VBA and I'm trying to make it so I can watch the macro scroll through cells. When I try to use sleep to slowly iterate over cells (using a for loop) Excel becomes unresponsive after ~20 iterations. It then hangs until the end and then comes back after the sub has executed fully.

Here is the code that makes it happen:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 50
        Sleep 250
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `DoEvents` to your loop.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 50
        Sleep 250
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        DoEvents '/ Add do events to return the resource to interface.
    Next i
End Sub
```